# What's this command - 0 */12 * * * root test -x /usr/bin/certbot -a \! -d /run/systemd/system && perl -e 'sleep int(rand(43200))' && certbot -q renew?

Tags: 20.04

```
0 */12 * * * root test -x /usr/bin/certbot -a \! -d /run/systemd/system && perl -e 'sleep int(rand(43200))' && certbot -q renew
```

I understand the meaning of `0 */12 * * *`

Following that is `root` which seems to be the username. What is the meaning of the `test -x....` onwards?

Answer (score 3):

This is a [crontab](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/CronHowto) entry. `root` specifies that the job must be run as user `root` (so, it's slightly more complex than the standard user crontab entry). The rest of the line is the job to run. The job is run every 12 hours.

The job is

```
test -x /usr/bin/certbot -a \! -d /run/systemd/system && perl -e 'sleep int(rand(43200))' && certbot -q renew
```

Basically, this checks whether Certbot is installed, waits a random time of up to 12 hours to avoid congestion, and then runs `certbot -q renew` to renew a certificate if necessary.

Cerbot auto-renewal setup is described [here](https://eff-certbot.readthedocs.io/en/stable/using.html#automated-renewals).